# LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio, and I followed a tutorial to get registration and login to the app.

Now I'm trying to add a code in my `activity_main.xml`, but I get error all the time.

Is it possible to have all 3 in the same xml. Or do I need to modify the first code?

LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

org xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
        android:onClick="logout"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the code I want in is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added this dependency `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'` in you build.gradle(app) file? Also change this `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to this `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`. You can have all 3 together by my understanding is that for the tutorial you need to replace the first layout snippet with the second one

Comment: you'll get better results if you ask an actual question in the title.  Nobody perusing the site will know what you need unless they visit the question link, currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the linear layout as per the below demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
         />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```